# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. .NET Framework 4

Tags: c#

I've searched online to understand the significance of this exception within the context of my program, but haven't been able to find a definitive solution or the underlying cause specific to my situation. I'm employing these methods to decrypt an encrypted model; however, upon attempting decryption, I encounter the following exception: 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.' Could someone advise me on how to address this issue? Below is the relevant section of my code where I retrieve the key and other necessary data.

```
 public class EncryptHelper
    {
        private static readonly byte[] _passBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptionHelper.DecryptData(SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue("ApiEncryptSecretKey"))));
      
        public static T Base64DecodeObject<T>(string encodedData)
        {
            try
            {

                string _decodedData = Base64DecodeString(encodedData);

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(_decodedData);
            }
            catch
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }

      
        public static string Base64DecodeString(string encodedData)
        {
            try
            {
                string incoming = encodedData
                    .Replace('_', '/')
                    .Replace('-', '+');

                switch (encodedData.Length % 4)
                {
                    case 2: incoming += "=="; break;
                    case 3: incoming += "="; break;
                }

                byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(incoming);

                byte[] bytesDecrypted = EncryptOrDecrypt(bytesToBeDecrypted, _passBytes, false);
               //bytesToBeDecrypted.Length = 128
               //_passBytes.Length = 32
                string _decodedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);

                return _decodedData;
            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        private static byte[] EncryptOrDecrypt(byte[] dataBytes, byte[] passwordBytes, bool isEncrypt)

        {

            byte[] _bytes = null;
            byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36 };

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())

            {

                using (RijndaelManaged _rij = new RijndaelManaged())

                {

                    Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);

                    _rij.KeySize = 256;

                    _rij.BlockSize = 128;
                    _rij.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    _rij.Key = key.GetBytes(_rij.KeySize / 8);

                    _rij.IV = key.GetBytes(_rij.BlockSize / 8);

                    _rij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    ICryptoTransform transform = isEncrypt ? _rij.CreateEncryptor() : _rij.CreateDecryptor();

                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))

                    {

                        cs.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);

                        cs.Close();

                    }

                    _bytes = ms.ToArray();

                }
            }

            return _bytes;

        }


    }
```

Comment: This exception is thrown if the padding is not PKCS#7 compliant after decryption. This is generally the case if decryption has failed and the padding has been corrupted. Possible causes are a wrong key, a different padding algorithm during encryption and decryption or a corrupted ciphertext. In the case of your code, e.g. a different password during encryption or decryption could trigger this exception, see online here https://dotnetfiddle.net/YVBOzp.